# Filter and display content on the left based on navigation selection using angular Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-material

This should be a simple question, currently am displaying widget types on the left side of the navigation and i have a widget array. Based on the Widget Title selection i need to filter the types from the widget and display on the right.

Here is the code which i have right now,

**App.js**

```
 $scope.WidgetTypes = [
    {
       title: 'Chart',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_insert_chart_24px.svg'
    },
    {

      title: 'Blogging',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_assignment_24px.svg'
    },
    {

      title: 'Advertising',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_av_timer_24px.svg'
    },
    {

      title: 'Custom',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_dashboard_24px.svg'
    },
    {

      title: 'Social Media',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_now_widgets_24px.svg'
    } ,
     {

      title: 'Web Analytics',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_gradient_24px.svg'
    }  
  ];
      $scope.Widgets = [
    {
       title: 'Google SpreadSheets',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_insert_chart_24px.svg',
       type:"Chart",
       Description:'Line, Area, Bar, Pie, Table'
    } ,

    {

      title: 'LinkedIn',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_dashboard_24px.svg',
       type:"Social Media",
         Description:'Connections, Network Updates'
    }, 
    {

      title: 'Pinterest',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_dashboard_24px.svg',
       type:"Social Media",
         Description:'Boards, Pins, Likes, Followers, Following'
    },
    {

      title: 'Google Analytics (Real Time)',
      icon: 'styles/css/images/icons/ic_dashboard_24px.svg',
       type:"Web Analytics",
         Description:'Audience, Traffic, Content, Conversions'
    }
  ];
```

**HTML:**

```
 <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="widget in Widgets ">
   <div layout="row" layout-margin>
     <div flex="60">
        <img ng-src="{{widget.icon}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{widget.title}}">
        <div class="md-list-item-text">
          <h4>{{ widget.title }}</h4>
          <h5>{{ widget.Description }}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div flex="20">
       <md-button style="width:100px"    class="md-raised">
        Add
       </md-button>
      </div>
    </div>
   <md-divider></md-divider>
 </md-list-item>
```

Here is the [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/DKfvofWT0lDWL991lCT7?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You in the right direction already you only have to implement which is selected & filter

```
$scope.filterWidgets = function(item)
 {
   $scope.selected = {};
  $scope.selected.type = item.title; 
  console.log(selected);
 };
```

and

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="widget in Widgets | filter : selected">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8M8tNAmV1dARIu4OfFcl?p=preview